# Can't upload multiple files using ajax and php

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, file

I'm trying to upload multiple files using jquery and PHP.
But my form data is not being submitted as required to the PHP page.
Please, can someone help me out writing the correct way of uploading files?

Below is my code:

index.php:

```
<form id="step17Form" action="" name="step17Form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div style="text-align :left; margin-left:15px"> <label><big>
                (<span style="color: red; font-family: Comic Sans MS;"><small style="font-weight: bold;">Note: Max File Size - 75KB</small></span>)</big></label>
        <br><br>
        <table style="text-align: centre; width: 800px; margin-left:15px" border="0" id="upload" cellpadding="6" cellspacing="6">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><br><label for="stuphoto"><span style="font-family: Comic Sans MS;">1. Student Photo</label></span>
                    </td>
                    <td><br><input id="file-upload" name="stuphoto" type="file" accept=".JPG" class="custom-file-upload" style="display: inline;"></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td><br><label for="stuadhar"><span style="font-family: Comic Sans MS;">2. Aadhar Card</label></span>
                    </td>
                    <td><br><input name="stuadhar" accept=".jpg,.pdf" class="custom-file-upload" type="file" style="display: inline;"></td>
                </tr>                                  
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <br>
    <input type="hidden" name="reason" value="step17" />
    <button type="submit" id="upload_save" class="btn btn-success"> Save And Next >></button>
</form>
```

JS:

```
$('#upload_save').click(function(){
            event.preventDefault();        

            $.ajax({
                url: 'controller.php',
                type: 'post',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: new FormData($(this).parents('form')),
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                success: function(suc){
                    alert(suc['msg']);
                },
                error: function(error){
                    alert(error);
                }
            });   
    });
```

controller.php:

```
     $reason = $_POST['reason'];
        var_dump($_FILES);
if ($reason === "step17" ) {
        var_dump($_FILES);
        $status=array();
        $uploaded_file=array();
        $document_type=array("Photo","Aadhar");
        $i=0;
        $j=0;
       foreach($_FILES as $key=>$file)
       {

          $status= uploadImage($key, $file_size=5000000, "../..".FILE_PATH_LOC );
          if($status['error']!==200 && $status['status']===false )
          {
            echo json_encode(array('status'=>'false','msg'=>"Error  ".$file['name']." ".$status['msg']));  
              break;
          }
       }
    }
```

Output of var_dump($_FILES):
array(0){
}
The issue I'm facing here is that the data I post is not being recognized in controller.php and control doesn't reach inside the if condition.

Comment: What exact issue are you facing? Please consider checking [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve your chances of getting answers

Comment: The issue I'm facing here is that the data I post is not being recognized in controller.php and control doesn't reach inside the if condition.

Comment: Please consider adding this info and the exact error message that you might be getting, to the question, so that its visible to people who can help you

Comment: try removing  dataType: 'json',

Comment: @suvartheec Question Edited.

Comment: @AhmedSunny Tried but that didn't help

Comment: @AhmedSunny why would you suggest that? `dataType: "json"` controls how jQuery processes the _response_ to the ajax call. And since the PHP clearly sends JSON as the response, it makes sense to include it. This setting has nothing to do with _sending_ the data, which is the problem being discussed. Please read http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ and improve your understanding of what the different options are used for.

Comment: @YashParekh `$('#upload_save').click(function(){` should be `$('#upload_save').click(function(event){` otherwise `event.preventDefault();` will not work, and your form may post back instead of doing the ajax request.

Comment: Also I think `data: new FormData($(this).parents('form')),` needs to be `data: new FormData($(this).parents('form')[0]),` since the FormData constructor expects a native JS form element, not a jQuery object

Comment: @ADyson In chrome it works even without giving event as the parameter. And form doesn't post back in this condition.

Comment: Look into your header, look how you send your data.

Comment: "In chrome it works even without giving event as the parameter"...I suspect it does a regular postback. Depending how long this takes to refresh the page, it might _also_ run the ajax code in parallel. This is not a desirable scenario. You need the preventDefault() to work properly. Another thing you can do to help with this is change `<button type="submit"` to `<button type="button"`, which means the button's default behaviour is not a postback

Comment: @ADyson True that. Tried but that still didn't work.

Comment: "didn't work" means what? Did _anything_ change? It might not be the whole solution but you should notice some difference if you are observing carefully enough. Did you also try my other suggestion at the same time (regarding the FormData object)?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make stuphoto as an array. Sor please try to change this line

```
 <td><br><input id="file-upload" name="stuphoto" type="file" accept=".JPG" class="custom-file-upload" style="display: inline;"></td>
```

To

```
<td><br><input id="file-upload" name="stuphoto[]" type="file" accept=".JPG" class="custom-file-upload" style="display: inline;"></td>
```

and

```
foreach($_FILES as $key=>$file)
```

to

```
foreach($_FILES['stuphoto']['name'] as $key=>$file)
```

Comment: I have a hidden input in form named `reason` whose value is `step17`. The control is not going inside the if condition in line 3 of controller.php

Comment: Did you try data: new FormData($(this).parents('form')[0]); instead data: new FormData($(this).parents('form')),

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are passing a jQuery object as the parameter to the FormData constructor when it takes an html form

```
$('#upload_save').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();        

        $.ajax({
            url: 'controller.php',
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: new FormData(this.form), // pass the form itself to the constructor
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function(suc){
                alert(suc['msg']);
            },
            error: function(error){
                alert(error);
            }
        });   
});
```